# Trigger an event when clipboard content changes

Tags: python, multithreading, macos, events, clipboard

I'm trying to get the clipboard content using a Python script on my Mac Lion.

I'm searching for an event or something similar, because if I use a loop, my application spends all its time watching the clipboard.

Any ideas?

Comment: For windows only, using the win32 api: https://abdus.dev/posts/monitor-clipboard/

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Have you thought about using an endless loop and "sleeping" between tries?
I used [pyperclip](http://coffeeghost.net/2010/10/09/pyperclip-a-cross-platform-clipboard-module-for-python/) for a simple PoC and it worked like a charm, and Windows and Linux.

```
import time
import sys
import os

import pyperclip

recent_value = ""
while True:
    tmp_value = pyperclip.paste()
    if tmp_value != recent_value:
        recent_value = tmp_value
        print("Value changed: %s" % str(recent_value)[:20])
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Instead of the `print`, do whatever you want.

---

Here is a complete multithreading example.

```
import time
import threading

import pyperclip

def is_url_but_not_bitly(url):
    if url.startswith("http://") and not "bit.ly" in url:
        return True
    return False

def print_to_stdout(clipboard_content):
    print ("Found url: %s" % str(clipboard_content))

class ClipboardWatcher(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, predicate, callback, pause=5.):
        super(ClipboardWatcher, self).__init__()
        self._predicate = predicate
        self._callback = callback
        self._pause = pause
        self._stopping = False
            
    def run(self):       
        recent_value = ""
        while not self._stopping:
            tmp_value = pyperclip.paste()
            if tmp_value != recent_value:
                recent_value = tmp_value
                if self._predicate(recent_value):
                    self._callback(recent_value)
            time.sleep(self._pause)
    
    def stop(self):
        self._stopping = True

def main():
    watcher = ClipboardWatcher(is_url_but_not_bitly, 
                               print_to_stdout,
                               5.)
    watcher.start()
    while True:
        try:
            print("Waiting for changed clipboard...")
            time.sleep(10)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            watcher.stop()
            break
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I create a subclass of threading.Thread, override the methods `run` and `__init__` and create an instance of this class. By calling `watcher.start()` (not `run()`!), you start the thread.

To safely stop the thread, I wait for <Ctrl>-C (keyboard interrupt) and tell the thread to stop itself.

In the initialization of the class, you also have a parameter `pause` to control how long to wait between tries.

Use the class ClipboardWatcher like in my example, replace the callback with what you do, e.g., `lambda x: bitly(x, username, password)`.

Comment: Thank you, yes pls tell me how to do this in a background thread my loop looks like that : `while True:
   pbstring = checkclipboard()

   if 'http://' in pbstring and not 'bit.ly' in pbstring:
    bitly(pbstring,username,key)
   
   else:
    print 'Waiting...'
    print pbstring
    time.sleep(5)` so at the moment my whole app waits for the loop and i couldn't do anything simultaneously..

Comment: Your script seems like a nice idea. You watch for URLs in the Clipboard and, if you find one, replace it with a shortened version?

Comment: OK now it appears that the rest of my code only works when i interrupt my while loop, any idea why ?

Comment: The second while-loop (in the `main`)-method was only intended as a placeholder for your actual code. Do I understand you correctly that you didn't remove it?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at `pyperclip` the meat of it on Macosx is :

```
import os
def macSetClipboard(text):
    outf = os.popen('pbcopy', 'w')
    outf.write(text)
    outf.close()

def macGetClipboard():
    outf = os.popen('pbpaste', 'r')
    content = outf.read()
    outf.close()
    return content
```

These work for me how do you get on?

I don't quite follow your comment on being in a loop.

---

**EDIT** Added 'orrid polling example that shows how `changeCount()` bumps up on each `copy` to the pasteboard. It's still not what the OP wants as there seems no event or notification for modifications to the `NSPasteboard`.

```
from LaunchServices import *
from AppKit import *
import os

from threading import Timer

def poll_clipboard():
    pasteboard = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
    print pasteboard.changeCount()

def main():
    while True:
        t = Timer(1, poll_clipboard)
        t.start()
        t.join()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I'm using the Appkit Framework: `NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()`, I need the loop to get new clipboard contents instantly.. because i have no callback event from the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

simple!

```
import os
def macSetClipboard(text):
    outf = os.popen('pbcopy', 'w')
    outf.write(text)
    outf.close()

def macGetClipboard():
    outf = os.popen('pbpaste', 'r')
    content = outf.read()
    outf.close()
    return content
current_clipboard = macGetClipboard()
while True:
   clipboard = macGetClipboard()
   
   if clipboard != current_clipboard:
       print(clipboard)
       macSetClipboard("my new string")
       print(macGetClipboard())
       break
```

Answer (score 1):

I originaly posted my answer on a duplicate [Run a python code when copying text with specific keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72647802/run-a-python-code-when-copying-text-with-specific-keyword/72648372#72648372)

Here the answer I came up with.

```
import clipboard
import asyncio


# Exemple function.
async def your_function():
    print("Running...")


async def wait4update(value):
    while True:
        if clipboard.paste() != value : # If the clipboard changed.
            return

async def main():
    value = clipboard.paste() # Set the default value.
    while True :
        update = asyncio.create_task(wait4update(value))
        await update
        value = clipboard.paste() # Change the value.    
        asyncio.create_task(your_function()) #Start your function.

asyncio.run(main())
```