# Python copy, cut and paste detection

Tags: python, copy, paste, cut

I am new to python, I am currently designing a program that runs in the background and i want it to detect if any copy, cut or paste operation is performed on a PC.
Or is there a way i can detect when control c, control v or control x is pressed by a user
Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i tried using pyhook, but even pyhook cannot specifically detect when i control-c or control-v is pressed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a key logger to detect key stroke like [this](https://github.com/ajinabraham/Xenotix-Python-Keylogger/blob/master/xenotix_python_logger.py) one. Other than that you can use key hooking using system calls.

Comment: i tried hooking but theres no way to detect when a control-c is pressed by hooking

Answer (score 0):

You could try to register changes to clipboard to trigger your event.

Take a look at this stack overflow question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685999/trigger-an-event-when-clipboard-content-changes)

Comment: None of the answers in that link register for changes; they do a busy-wait-sleep loop.