# Run a python code when copying text with specific keyword

Tags: python, clipboard

I am new to Python, trying to write a code to parse text into a certain format and copy it to the clipboard, which I have achieved. Now I am looking for a way to automatically run the python code when I copy the text to clipboard and if the text has a certain keyword.  so that as soon as my text content is copied, it will be parsed and readily available to be pasted on a text editor.

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685999/trigger-an-event-when-clipboard-content-changes ?

Comment: you could use the clipboard module. Check the content of your clipboard like 10 times a second using clipboard.paste() and if it's not the same as the previous value, you change the value and execute your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import clipboard
import asyncio


# Exemple function.
async def your_function():
    print("Running...")


async def wait4update(value):
    while True:
        if clipboard.paste() != value : # If the clipboard changed.
            return

async def main():
    value = clipboard.paste() # Set the default value.
    while True :
        update = asyncio.create_task(wait4update(value))
        await update
        value = clipboard.paste() # Change the value.       
        asyncio.create_task(your_function()) #Start your function.

asyncio.run(main())
```

Comment: PS: if you want to stop the program with a keystroke, you can use keyboard and sys and add an if statement in the wait4update function, example: elif keyboard.is_pressed('f4') == True: sys.exit()

Comment: this is perfect, your code solves my problem. Thank you !

Comment: could you please close the topic if my solution is good enough ?