# How can I create a program that runs commands as soon as I copy something to clipboard

Tags: python, python-3.x, clipboard

I want to write a program that will run a few lines on any piece of data or string upon copying to clipboard, is there a way to do this? I cant find much information about it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Trigger an event when clipboard content changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14685999/trigger-an-event-when-clipboard-content-changes)

Comment: https://abdus.dev/posts/monitor-clipboard/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

It has the `pyperclip.waitForPaste()` function, which should do exactly what you want. I had issues trying it with Linux Fedora, but it should be no problem on most Systems.